# Loop through nested object to calculate the value using ES6

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

```
{
  "activityDetails": [
    {
      "activityDate": "02-05-2020 00:00:00",
      "pointDetails": [
        {
          "points": 5000,
          "pointType": "SSM"
        },
        {
          "points": 9652,
          "pointType": "JSM"
        },
        {
          "points": 4826,
          "pointType": "BQS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "activityDate": "03-05-2020 00:00:00",
      "pointDetails": [
        {
          "points": 78000,
          "pointType": "SSM"
        },
        {
          "points": 9952,
          "pointType": "JSM"
        },
        {
          "points": 4926,
          "pointType": "BQS"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to calculate point in ES6. Basically I need add pointType SSM and JSM  i.e  5000 + 9652 = 14652.

i tried the following to iterate over the object to calculate the points.

```
const rates = this.activityList.map((item: { pointDetails: any; }) => item.pointDetails)
                this.activityList.reduce((sum: any, rates: any) => {
                    if (rates.pointType === 'SSM' || rates.pointType === 'JSM') {
                      sum += rates.sum;
                    }
                    console.log(sum);
                    return sum;
                  }, 0)
```

Comment: How does RxJS come into this? Where are the observables?

Answer (score 0):

Ultra basic?

```
let result = 0;

this.activityList.forEach((activity) => {
  activity.pointDetails.forEach((point) => {
    if (point.pointType === ''JSM' || point.pointType === 'SSM') {
      result += point.points;
    }
  });
});
```